# How to query utf-16 encoded XML files stored as varbinary?

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, full-text-search, xml-encoding

I want to run Full-Text Search on XML files that are stored as `varbinary` in SQL Server 2016 to find phrases (id, names, phones etc.) in those files. The problem is that the query doesn't find UTF-16 encoded files.

I have the following tables

Table **Files**:

| Id | Filename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | utf8-encoded.xml |
| 2 | utf16-encoded.xml |

Table FileContent:

| Id | Content | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0x444ae9b... | XML |
| 2 | 0x422de56... | XML |

and a view:

```
CREATE VIEW Search 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
    SELECT 
        e.Id, e.Filename, c.[Content], c.[Type]
    FROM 
        Files AS f 
    INNER JOIN 
        FileContent AS c ON c.Id = f.Id
```

Then I execute a full-text search query in C# in .NET Framework 4.6.1 using Dapper:

```
var searchTerm = "xxxxx"; // from user
var query = "SELECT * FROM Search s WHERE CONTAINS(s.Content, @searchTerm)";
var data = connection.Query<File>(query, new {searchTerm});
...
```

Changing Dapper parameter to sql-injectable string concatenation like this: `WHERE CONTAINS(s.Content, " + searchTerm" + ")"` doesn't change anything.

The query finds UTF-8 encoded XML files but not UTF-16 encoded. I believe that this is not Dapper-related issue.

How can I fix this to be able to find UTF-16 encoded XML files too? Does SQL Server's full-text search even work with UTF-16 encoded XML files?

Comment: fulltext works over textual columns.  So, I suggest you try changing the column to be nvarchar(max) and try again.

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT It's a production database, I can't change this table.

Comment: Don't know what's in your FileContent table but it doesn't seem to be XML data (neither UTF-8 nor UTF-16 encoded)... `0x444ae9b...` is `DJé...` and `0x422de56...` is `C-å...`

Comment: It's random hex. In real Content table there is XML data, trust me :)

Comment: binary fields don't have collations or distinguish between encodings (UTF-8 vs. -16 vs. ANSI, etc).  Here's an example using filetable (where the blobs are stored on the file system).  It won't help your prod system without changes, but hopefully it will give you a recipe to test future designs. https://oakdome.com/programming/SQL_FileTables_FullTextSearch.php

Comment: Depending on what type of searching you are doing, you could possibly use XQuery